# Is the destructor called when a delegating constructor throws?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, constructor

It is well known that if a constructor throws, then all fully constructed sub-objects will be destroyed in reverse order including member data and all kinds of base classes. The destructor does not get called for non-delegating constructors though. For a delegating constructor the object has been constructed when the constructor body is entered, but construction continues somewhat. Therefore the question arises whether the destructor of the class is called, if the delegating constructor throws an exception from within its body?

```
class X
{
public:
    X();
    X(int) : X() { throw std::exception(); } // is ~X() implicitely called?
    ~X();
};
```

Comment: `X` is not a member object of `X`, so why would its destructor be called?

Comment: @Praetorian: Because it's been fully constructed by the delegating constructor; and because the standard says it will be.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14386840/981959

Comment: good question, but duplicate, hence -1

Comment: I really don't like it when a question is considered to be a duplicate even though the original question was asked in such a way that you can hardly find it by searching. At least I hope that people who are looking for an answer to this question will find it here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The rule is that the destructor is called for all fully
constructed objects.  The object is considered fully constructed
once any constructor has finished, including the delegated
constructor (even though the program continues in another
constructor).

Comment: Can you cite a standard reference for this (although it makes intuitive sense)?

Comment: @MarkB §15.2/2 "[...] Similarly, if the non-delegating constructor for
an object has completed execution and a delegating constructor
for that object exits with an exception, the object’s destructor
will be invoked.[...]".

Comment: I am not sure I like that behavior.

Comment: Interesting... This makes possible to use a private delegated constructor and a public delegating constructor to write a two-stage constructor, just for exception-safety issues. I wonder if it can offer any real advantage.

Comment: @LokiAstari  Nothing else makes sense (although I can understand your worries).  The non-delegating constructor has put the class into a defined state (and possibly allocated resources which need freeing), so the destructor must be called.  In a delegating constructor, the code in the constructor body is in a sort of limbo: it's in a constructor, but it's not part of the principle construction of the class.

Comment: @rodrigo how would you use that for exception safety?

Comment: So what should the destructor do in the case where the delegating constructor may also have allocated resources which need freeing?

Comment: @JamesKanze: If the object is fully formed after the delagate is complete. How does this affect cleanup of the memory? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17658902/14065

Comment: @ArneMertz: Not sure, but... for example a database connection: it will create the connection in the delegated constructor, and run the initialization queries in the delegating constructor. That way, if an exception is thrown during the queries the connection will be cleaned up automatically.

Comment: @Chowlett The class is fully constructed when the delegate has finished.  After that, all the delegator can do is modify values.  It's up to the class author and designer to ensure that the destructor takes into account any modifications which occur after the class has been fully constructed.  Whether they take place in an arbitrary member function, or in the delegating constructor body.

Answer (score 7):

> The lifetime of an object begins when any constructor (i.e., in the
>   case of delegation, the ultimate target constructor) is successfully
>   completed. For the purposes of [C++03] §3.8, “the constructor call
>   has completed” means any constructor call. This means that an
>   exception thrown from the body of a delegating constructor will cause
>   the destructor to be invoked automatically.

[source](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1986.pdf).

And [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/delegating-constructors/184401647) is a nice article about delegating constructors, should anybody want to read it.

Comment: Except that the source you cite is an early proposal for the feature.  The exact words you cite did _not_ make it into the final standard, or at least I cannot find them.  And the "nice article" you cite is more about what to do when you don't have delegating constructors.

Comment: Corroborated by https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw
> If a delegating constructor exits with an exception after the non-delegating constructor successfully completed, the destructor for this object is called.