# Is the memory automatically reclaimed when a delegating constructor throws?

Tags: c++, c++11

Following on from this:  [Is the destructor called when a delegating constructor throws?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17657761/14065)

```
class X
{
public:
    X()       {};
    X(int)    : X() { throw std::exception(); }
    X(double)       { throw std::exception(); }
    ~X();
};
```

What about dynamic memory? Normally an exception in the constructor means the object was not fully constructed and thus the memory is cleanedup and not lost.

But the argument in the previous question is that the object is fully constructed (or fully initialized) after the delegate completes. How does this affect reclaiming the memory? I would hope that memory is still cleanedup!

```
int main()
{
    new X(5);        // new called 
                     // delete called because delegate completed.
                     // I assume:  
                     //      Memory re-claimed (because constructor did not complete)
                     //      I assume the C++11 standard adjusted to compensate.
                     //      As a constructor did complete.
}
```

Compared too:

```
int main()
{
    new X(5.0);      // new called 
                     //    Delete **NOT** called
                     // Memory re-claimed (because constructor did not complete)
}
```

If the memory is cleaned up, then the definition of when the memory is cleanup needs to be altered from C++03 spec. How is the behavior changed?

Comment: The standard says that "if the non-delegating constructor for an object has completed execution and a delegating constructor for that object exits with an exception, the object’s destructor will be invoked." So the destructor is invoked. If that doesn't answer your question, it's insufficiently clear, at least to me.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Not destructed but reclaimed. In C++03 an exception in the constructor does not leak, because an exception that escapes the constructor leaves the object not fully formed. But here the object is fully formed. My question is really how has the handling changed from C++03.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You should post that as an answer (ideally with the reference). I see that as a bit of a dangerous thing though...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I would, except it's the answer to the question the OP referenced. So I was puzzled why he asked the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the destructor called when a delegating constructor throws?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657761/is-the-destructor-called-when-a-delegating-constructor-throws)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: There is a difference between the destructor being called and the memory being re-claimed. In C++03 all members that are fully formed are destructed but there memory is not reclaimed (as they part of the bigger object). Since the bigger object is fully formed I can see the destructor being called but does this mean you reclaim dynamically allocated memory? Well yes I doubt there is a hole left by the committee. But this means the definition of the circumstances under which it is reclaimed happen.

Comment: @LokiAstari I don't understand what "dynamically allocated memory" means in this context.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr<>` is deprecated in C++11

Comment: It's not clear what actually is asked here. Why should it make a difference for the memory reclaim, whether or not the destructor was called?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I have added to the question. Does this help?

Comment: @Walter: It does not. But I want to understand the exact definition in the new standard. In C++03 it(memory) was reclaimed if the constructor did not complete. Here in C++11 it is reclaimed even when a constructor did complete (according to the linked question the object is fully formed when delegate constructor completes). As it turns out my mental model of when memory allocation is done was not correct.

Comment: @Loki: For an exception that occurs in any other member function, it's up to the caller to arrange deletion of the object, because the caller has a pointer to the object, the result of the original new-expression.  If an exception occurs in a delegating constructor (and is not caught within the constructor) then **the new-expression terminates via exception and the caller never receives a pointer which could be used to free the object**.  Therefore the compiler arranges for the (fully constructed) object to be destroyed and the memory returned.

Comment: @LokiAstari It's not clear what dynamic memory in particular you're talking about.  If it is the memory allocated by `new X(5)`, then it will be reclaimed "If any part of the object initialization [..] terminates by throwing an exception" (as bames53 makes clear in his quote from the standard).  The code in the delegating constructor is part of the initialization, even if the object is fully constructed before it executes.

Comment: Memory allocation is complete before any constructors run.  But the compiler handling of a new-expression ensures that the memory is either returned from the new-expression or freed (barring process termination during evaluation of the constructors).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes I agree my question is answered below. My worry was based on my understand of the C++03 standard (My understanding was flawed (I assumed C++03 it was described as reclaiming if the object was not fully created)).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the constructor called by `new` throws an exception then the memory allocated by `new` is automatically deallocated. Delegating constructors change nothing in this regard.

> If any part of the object initialization described above<sup>76</sup> terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable deallocation function can be found, the deallocation function is called to free the memory in which the object was being constructed
>
> *— C++11 [expr.new] 5.3.4/18*

The 'any part of the object initialization' described includes both the constructor calls and evaluation of the expressions passed to the constructor.

Also, this behavior is specified identically in the C++98 standard [C++98 5.4.3/17]. The only difference delegating constructors make is if your mental model was previously based on the object being completely constructed or not. Given delegating constructors that's no longer equivalent to the actual specification of when deallocation occurs.

---

In your first example:

```
new X(5);
```

The order of events is:

- allocation function called
- X(int) called
- - X() called (and exits successfully)
- - X(int) throws an exception
- - ~X() called
- X(int) exits via exception
- deallocation function called because object initialization failed
- exception continues to propagate normally

With the second example

```
new X(5.0);
```

- allocation function called
- X(double) called
- X(double) fails with an exception
- deallocation function called because object initialization failed
- exception continues to propagate normally

You can observe this behavior by replacing the allocation and deallocation functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <new>
    
void *operator new(std::size_t s) {
    if (void *ptr = std::malloc(s)) {
        std::cout << "allocation\n";
        return ptr;
    }
    throw std::bad_alloc{};
}

void operator delete(void *ptr) noexcept {
    if (ptr) {
        std::cout << "deallocation\n";
        std::free(ptr);
    }
}

struct S {
    S() {};
    S(int) : S{} { throw std::exception(); }
    S(double) { throw std::exception(); }
    ~S() { std::cout << "destructor\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "test 1\n";
    try {
        new S(1);
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "exception caught\n";
    }

    std::cout << "test 2\n";
    try {
        new S(1.);
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "exception caught\n";
    }
}
```

The correct output of this program is:

```
test 1
allocation
destructor
deallocation
exception caught
test 2
allocation
deallocation
exception caught
```

Comment: Yes.  I think the key is that returning from the primary constructor is _not_ the end of initialization.

Comment: Your edit left something out.  In `new X(5)`, since `X::X()` succeeded, `X::~X()` will be called before deallocation.