# object destruction & delegating constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657761/is-the-destructor-called-when-a-delegating-constructor-throws/17657917) about delegating constructors, a destructor is called when the first constructor has finished.
This is consistent with the following code:

```
struct test {
    test() { std::cout << "default constr\n"; }
    test(int) : test() { std::cout << "argument constr\n"; throw int{}; }
    ~test() { std::cout << "destr\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        test t{3};
    } catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "caught\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
default constr
argument constr
destr
caught
```

But, Stroustrup says the following in his book (4th edition, page 503):

> An object is not considered constructed until its constructor completes (...). When using a
> delegating constructor, the object is not considered constructed until the delegating constructor
> completes – just completing the delegated-to constructor is not sufficient. A destructor will not be
> called for an object unless its original constructor completed.

Am I misreading this or does he mean something else?

Comment: i am a little confused. Stroustrup says that both constructors must be called before the desstructor can run and thats what we see in the output. Am I missing something?

Comment: oh its about the "A destructror will not be called ..." ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I misreading this

I don't think so.

> or does he mean something else?

I don't think so.

This seems to be an error in the book as far as I can tell. The book's description may be based on the original delegating constructors [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1581.pdf). The behaviour was changed in following revisions of the proposal.